# How to remove underline of specific link cells in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Some columns of my datagridview are link columns. Based on data fetched I'd like to set the LinkBehavior of certain cells to NeverUnderLine. Trouble is that I can iterate only through DataGridViewCell and not DataGridViewLinkCell. DataGridViewCell doesn't has the LinkBehavior property (which is quite logical).

So how exactly do I set the LinkBehavior property of a cell?

```
      foreach (DataGridViewCell dcell in dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells)
      {
        if (dcell.Value.ToString() == "Error")
        {
         dcell.Style.ApplyStyle(style);

         //dcell.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.NeverUnderline;

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if you can type cast your cell DataGridViewCell  to a link cell DataGridViewLinkCell and change its properties.

```
DataGridViewLinkCell linkCell = dcell as DataGridViewLinkCell
if(linkCell != null)
//your code...
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. kinda dumb of me to not try that :)